# Dice roll in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function rolldice() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1) + 1);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1) + 1);
    var dicetotal = x + y;
    var double = 0;
    $('.dice1').attr('id', "dice" + x);
    $('.dice2').attr('id', "dice" + y);
    if (x == y) { //<----checking if there is a double
        var double = double++; //<---increment double count
        //Now reroll the dice, but if you hit 3 doubles in a row, you get message go to jail.
    }
};
```

I want to know if I am going to need some loop...Please help me. This is part of a monopoly game. What do i have to add in the code, to make it loop if there is a double.

Comment: Don't call your variable `double`. You will thank me later.

Comment: If you add a loop here, you are not able to accept user input between the two rolls. Is that really what you want in a Monopoly game?

Comment: The second `var double` is a redefinition. Just `double++;` is sufficient.

Comment: Hmm you are correct. Once a double is hit, i would have to move the monnopoly piece, depending on where it lands, the player might not have to roll the dice again. But I can add those condition later right?

Comment: You should have an indicator whose turn it is at the moment. If anybody rolls *no* double, you should update this indicator

Comment: Yes I am trying to add functionality as I go along, the game is at the moment single player.

Comment: If you use a loop within this function in this situation, you'll either have to change it later, or so some serious work around.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest, that you ignore the doubles for now and code the rest of the game and add the roll-again-on-double later. It is easier this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to make an recursive call:

```
var dbl = 0;
function rolldice() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1) + 1);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1) + 1);
    var dicetotal = x + y;
    $('.dice1').attr('id', "dice" + x);
    $('.dice2').attr('id', "dice" + y);
    if (x == y) { //<----checking if there is a double
        dbl++; //<---increment double count
        if(dbl%3==0) $('.out').attr('id', "jail");
        //Now reroll the dice, but if you hit 3 doubles in a row, you get message go to jail.
        rolldice();
    }
};
```

Comment: "double" is a restricted/reserved word. Rename your variable please.

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing @ If(dbl%3==0)? I understand that you are checking whether dbl is equal to 3, but not sure exactly why you have a %.

Comment: if dbl remainder is 0, then is divisible by 3 (modulo op),and then you can reset dbl to 0 if you wantand so on

Comment: Oh ok. I wanted to change the value of the #roll (its id) button, to "roll again"? If the condition is met.

Comment: What? Why to change button id what is the scope?

Comment: When the player first presses the button says "ROLL", so when the player gets a double, the button will say "Roll Again", i got that work with a getelementbyID.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create something like this:

```
var double = 0;

function rolldice(){

    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((6-1)+1) + 1);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((6-1)+1) + 1);

    var dicetotal = x + y;
    $('.dice1').attr('id',  "dice" + x);
    $('.dice2').attr('id', "dice" +y);

    if(x==y) {
       if (double < 3) {
          double++; // increase dobule
          rolldice(); // Call rolldice again...
       } else {
          // Here there is 3 in a row....
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has some complications. When there is a change of player, you need to reset the value of your variable for checking double rolls.

Do the following:

```
var dblRolls;
function userChange(){//call this on change of user
    dblRolls=0;
    rollDice();
}
function rolldice() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1) + 1);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1) + 1);
    var dicetotal = x + y;
    var double = 0;
    $('.dice1').attr('id', "dice" + x);
    $('.dice2').attr('id', "dice" + y);
    if (x == y) { //<----checking if there is a double
        dblRoll++; //<---increment double count
        if(dblRoll==3)
        //jail
        else
            rollDice();
    }
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a loop.

Instead add the doubles counter as a parameter for the `rolldice()` function and call the function from within itself:

```
function rolldice(doubleCount) {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1) + 1);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1) + 1);
    var dicetotal = x + y;
    $('.dice1').attr('id', "dice" + x);
    $('.dice2').attr('id', "dice" + y);
    if (x == y) { //<----checking if there is a double
       doubleCount++;
       if (doubleCount == 3)
       {
           //go to jail
       }
       else
       {
           rolldice(doubleCount);
       }
    }
};
```

The initial call for a player's first roll would look like `rolldice(0);`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, besides this is more than two hours old and has already 4 answers, I want to add my 2 cents.

You state you want to make a Monopoly game. After most, if not all, dice rolls the player has to make decisions. That means after each roll you wait for user input (e.g., some button presses).

All other answers postet suggest to use recursive calls in some way. Instead I suggest to store the number of doubles alongside with the current player in some global variable. You do not use a loop, but instead something like:

```
var doubleCount = 0;

function rolldice() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1) + 1);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((6 - 1) + 1) + 1);
    var dicetotal = x + y;
    $('.dice1').attr('id', "dice" + x);
    $('.dice2').attr('id', "dice" + y);
    if (x == y) { //<----checking if there is a double
        doubleCount++; //<---increment double count
        if (doubleCount > 2) {
          // Got to Jail
        }
    }
    // Proceed as usual and come back to this, when the user presses the "Roll" Button again
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This script works:

```
function rollDice(){
   var dice1 = document.getElementById("dice1");
   var dice2 = document.getElementById("dice2");
   var status = document.getElementById("status");
   var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
   var d2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
   var diceTotal = d1 + d2;
   dice1.innerHTML = d1;
   dice2.innerHTML = d2;
   status.innerHTML = "You rolled "+diceTotal+".";
   if(d1 == d2){
      status.innerHTML += "<br />DOUBLES! You get a free turn!!";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution.

```
function rolldice(dbl=0){
var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*((6-1)+1) + 1);
var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*((6-1)+1) + 1);
if(x===y){
   if(dbl!==3){
      dbl++;
      rolldice(dbl);
   }else{
      //goto jail
   }
}else{
    //no double
    dbl=0;
}
}
```

or

```
function rolldice(dbl=0){
var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*((6-1)+1) + 1);
var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*((6-1)+1) + 1);
if(x===y&&dbl!==3)
    dbl++;
    rolldice(dbl);
}else if(x===y&&dbl===3){
    //goto jail
}else{
    //no double
    dbl=0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Created Dice Roll with Rolling animation effect using **Vanilla JavaScript**.

This will allow you to "roll" dice in 2D, giving you a random set of dice after 1 second.

```js
const DICE_NUMBER = {
  1: '⚀',
  2: '⚁',
  3: '⚂',
  4: '⚃',
  5: '⚄',
  6: '⚅'
}


function rollDice(){
   const [dice1, dice2, status] = [document.getElementById("dice1"), document.getElementById("dice2"), document.getElementById("status")] 
   
  const MAX_NUM = 6;
  let d1 = 0
  let d2 = 0
  
  // Rolling Dice Animation
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    d1 = (Math.random()*MAX_NUM) + 1 | 0
    d2 = (Math.random()*MAX_NUM) + 1 | 0
    dice1.innerText = DICE_NUMBER[d1]
    dice2.innerText = DICE_NUMBER[d2]
    dice1.setAttribute('data-num',  d1)
    dice2.setAttribute('data-num',  d2)
  }, 80)
  
  // Final Result
  setTimeout(()=> {
    clearInterval(interval)
    const result = (d1 == d2) ? `<mark>DOUBLES!</mark> You get a <mark>FREE</mark> turn!!` : ''
    status.innerHTML = result
  }, 1000)
  
}
```

```css
.dice { font-size: 90px; }
[data-num='1'] { color: hotpink }
[data-num='2'] { color: blue }
[data-num='3'] { color: tan }
[data-num='4'] { color: purple }
[data-num='5'] { color: orange }
[data-num='6'] { color: green }
```

```html
<button onclick="rollDice()">Click here  Roll Dice</button>
<div id="status"></div>
<span class="dice" id="dice1"></span>
<span class="dice" id="dice2"></span>
```